# BASH: How can I combine two (or more) variable string manipulations in one step?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables

Is it possible to combine two or more string manipulation functionalities of a variable in BASH *(or any other standard Linux command)*?

Let's say *e.g.* I have the variable `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` which holds the string `ubuntu:GNOME`.
Now, I can retrieve the second substring by `${XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP##*:}` → `GNOME`.
I can also retrieve the lower case string through `${XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP,,}` → `ubuntu:gnome`.

But how can I combine both functions *(→ `gnome`)* in **one** – *simple* – command without using a redirection to `sed`, `awk`, `grep` or any other of these – *quite heavy weighted* – commands and without an additional buffer storage step? e.g.:

```
local mybuffer="${XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP##*:}"
echo "${mybuffer,,}"
```

I want to avoid such a "sub-script" or function call construct to achieve this and I already tried any combination of both mentioned but it seems to be futile.
Is there any other way?
Or do I need to upgrade bash? *(using: GNU bash 4.3.11)*
Or can any other shell do that?

Comment: `zsh` can do it, with the `L` parameter expansion flag ex. `${(L)XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP##*:}`

Comment: @steeldriver: Oohhh, nice! _THAT_ is exactly what I was looking for! Time for `zsh`. Thank you very much! :))

Comment: @steeldriver may as well post that as an answer since the OP also asked for other shells.

Comment: @terdon: d'accord

Answer (score 4):

You could do this in `bash` if you use `read` to read two variables:

```
$ echo "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP"
ubuntu:GNOME
$ IFS=':' read var1 var2 <<<"${XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP@L}"
$ echo "$var2"
gnome
```

The `${variable@L}` construct returns the value of `$variable` converted to lower case. Then, `IFS=':' read` sets the input field separator to `:` for the `read` command, this way the global IFS is left unchanged after the command exits, and then `read var1 var2` will separate its input on `:` and save the result in the two variables `var1` and `var2`. Note that if you have more than one `:` on the same line in the input, `var1` will have everything up to the first `:` and `var2` everything else.
Finally, `<<<` is a "here string", a simple way to pass a variable as input to a command.

Comment: Nice workaround! But unfortunately this construct is way to long and presumably with to many background processes _(→ KISS principle)_. BTW, with this bash version I think I can adopt the combination similar to the zsh proposal from @steeldriver above. Anyway, 1+ for the inspiration!

Comment: @Jens it is long and unwieldy to write, absolutely. Zsh tends to be more elegant with this sort of thing. But many background processes? Why? This is all 100% bash builtin tools, I don't think there will be much (any?) forking involved.

Comment: Good point! I'm just trying to implement something like an _"uniform directive/constant"_ that really shouldn't take to much coding _and_ background processing. Meanwhile I anyway came to the point that `zsh` might be counterproductive due to the fact that it seems to be not widely distributed. So it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Jens zsh is becoming more and more popular, and is the default shell on some non-Ubuntu systems (macOS as far as I know, but maybe others) but yes, you cannot assume it will be available. But then you also cannot assume that bash is available :). For true portability, you need to stick to a basic POSIX shell like `sh` or `dash`. My answer depends on bashisms, the portable way would be to pipe to a portable external tool like `sed` or `perl`. All of this is off topic here though, we only handle Ubuntu. You might want to check out [linux.se] for portability questions.

Comment: sh, dash, bash, zsh, etc. … too many choices … I think I lost track of the global view with this detail ;oP I must admit, I did not consider this shell issue yet. Maybe for now I should stay with `bash`. From this perspective your code looks much better the more I think about it xD

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bash5 (not bash4) script:

```
part2() {
   local -n var=$1
   var=${var#*:}
}
lc() {
   local -n var=$1
   var=${var,,}
}
fred="ubuntu:gnome"
part2 fred
lc fred
printf "%s\n" "$fred"
```

Output:

```
gnome
```

The functions `part2` and `lc` modify the variable whose name is passed to them, without forking.  In the end, the original variable (`fred`) has been modified.  You still need the extra variable though.

The alternative, which should work on bash4, is something like this:

```
part2() { printf "%s" "${1#*:}"; }
lc()    { printf "%s" "${1,,}" ; }
fred="ubuntu:GNOME"
printf "%s\n" "$(lc "$(part2 "$fred")")"
```

which does not modify any variables (it only manipulates values), but it does create extra forks.

Comment: First of all: thank you for your effort. The result is fine. FYI: _all_ of your code is Bash4 in deed ;-). I really do appreciate modular programming, but in this case I was more looking for a single command code or alternatively a one-liner. Sorry, but thank you very much anyway.